# detect which button has been clicked and submit with ajx

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need help getting a value of a clicked button and send this information using AJAX. the two scripts work individually. but i need the "buttonvalue" to be passed to AJAX "data" value "action". what i am using is below.

```
   $("document").ready(function(){

     $(".js-ajax-php-json").on("click", "button[name=mysqljob]", function (){
    var buttonvalue = $(this).attr("value");
    alert(buttonvalue);
    });

  $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){ 

    var data = {"action": buttonvalue};

    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "phpVars/ajaxUpload.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html(
         data["form"]
        );
      //  alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prevent the form from submitting do what you want then post the data via an ajax call. Try the following:

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $(".js-ajax-php-json").on("click", "button[name=mysqljob]", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var buttonvalue = $(this).attr("value");
        var data = {"action": buttonvalue, "formData": $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data) };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "phpVars/ajaxUpload.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $(".the-return").html(
                    data["form"]
                );
  //            alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Not tested.